# Running Worker in background.js in Firefox Extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, webassembly, firefox-addon-webextensions, browser-extension

What is the correct way of running Workers in Firefox `background.js`? Content-Security-Policy(CSP) seems to be blocking the script. (I am using MV2 because I want to run Web Assembly.)

- I tried using `data:application/javascript;base64,...` but `data:` to `script-src` in `manifest.json` is ignored by Firefox.

> ⚠️Reading manifest: Error processing content_security_policy: ‘script-src’ directive contains a forbidden data: protocol source

- Then I tried doing `Worker('worker.js')` and exposing `worker.js` in `web_accessible_resources` in `manifest.json`. However, this is also blocked by CSP even when I have CSP `default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';`

> ❗️Content-Security-Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”).

- I also tried adding the `sha-256` hash to CSP, but still, the script is blocked.

So what is the correct way of passing scripts to `Worker` in background?

Comment: There's no need to do anything special, neither CSP, nor web_accessible_resources. Assuming worker.js is in your extension directory, `new Worker('worker.js')` just works. Make sure the path is correct though.